# Reading in 'parallel' from postgre using npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Sorry, if this question seems like a duplicate, but I was not able to figure out a solution from other answers.
I have a postgre DB that I am accessing using Npgsql.
I have multiple clients reading from the DB simultaneously.
I am getting exception - Operation is in progress.
I know the reason behind it.
I am using

```
public bool ReadRecord(arguments)
{
....
    NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Calling routine

```
private void GetBundleIdAndIsWat(arguments)
{
...
    TaskQueue.GlobalInstance.AddTaskQueue(new Task<bool>(ReadRecord, InputData), tokenSource);
...
}
```

and while the reader is not disposed off for a given thread, the other one is not able to execute a command.

How do all multiple threads read from the DB simultaneously?
Does ExecuteReaderAsync allow only one thread to execute the command at a time?
In this case, I won't be able to read at the same time, right?
I read about **Connection Pool** but don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] showing how you are trying to do two reads in parallel. Can this work? Yes it can - but we can't explain what you are doing wrong without seeing some code.

Comment: @mjwills, updated. Hope this is sufficient.

Comment: @mjwills, thanks for your interest. While I was preparing a minimal reproducible code, I received an answer from Dennis. Turns out that I was sharing my connection among all the tasks. Now, I am  using a connection per task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do all multiple threads read from the DB simultaneously?

It looks like you're sharing single database connection between parallel operations.
Just use separate connection per operation.

Note, that:

- number of parallel connections is limited both by connection pool size and PostgreSQL. Connection pool size is limited by default to 100 connections, and you can change it by setting `MaxPoolSize` parameter in connection string. PostgreSQL limits this by `max_connections` parameter in `postgresql.conf`, and by default this one is also set to 100. Note, that a hundred of parallel connections is a rather big value, don't increase it until you *really* need this.
- you mentioned threads, but this is a good candidate to use parallel *tasks* and asynchronous code instead of threads. This also will allow to utilize connections in more efficient way.

> I read about Connection Pool but don't really know how to implement it

You don't need to implement connection pool yourself.
Well-done ADO .NET provider already implements it.
Just use connections, commands, and readers as usual: create, use, **dispose**.

Comment: I was indeed using one connection shared by all the tasks (actually using tasks; not threads). Cheers!!